# Law of large numbers question

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $a, b, p \in (0, 1)$. What is the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$? By considering this sum and applying the weak law of large numbers, identify the limit
>
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}:an<r<bn} \binom{n}{r} p^r(1 − p)^{n−r}
> $$
> in the cases **(i)** $p < a$; **(ii)** $a < p < b$; **(iii)** $b < p$.

I feel like the answers should be
**(i)** $0$,
**(ii)** $1$,
**(iii)** $0$,
but I don't know how to answer this question rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLLN says that the probability that the sample mean of $n$ Bernoulli variables deviates from $p$ by more than any $\epsilon > 0$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. This means the probability that a binomial random variable deviates from $np$ by more than $n \epsilon$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Now take $0<\epsilon<\min \{ |p-a|,|p-b| \}$. Then in case (i) and (iii), $(an,bn)$ doesn't intersect with $((p-\epsilon)n,(p+\epsilon)n)$, thus it is contained in the complement, so

$$P(X \in (an,bn)) \leq P(X \not \in ((p-\epsilon)n,(p+\epsilon)n)) \to 0.$$

In case (ii), instead $(an,bn)$ contains all of $((p-\epsilon)n,(p+\epsilon)n)$ so you have

$$P(X \in (an,bn)) \geq P(X \in ((p-\epsilon)n,(p+\epsilon)n)) \to 1.$$

It may help to draw a number line to help see the set relationships going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you have time, would you be able to flesh out what you wrote in the last sentence please? I'm not sure how to do what you described.

Comment: @sph0 Does this help?

Comment: Thank you @Ian!